# I am a AWS newbie and I can't connect to my DB instance

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services

I am trying to do something ridiculously simple in PHP - connect to a DB instance. I can connect to it from my query browser using the endpoint provided but when I try to do it in the server PHP code, it throws an error of:

> "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL. Debugging errno: 2003 Debugging
>   error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ENDPOINT' (110) "

(I replaced my actual endpoint with the word ENDPOINT for security reasons)

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I can point my MySQL query browser sitting on my desktop to that endpoint, provide the username/password and all is good. But as soon as I try to do it in the code with a `mysqli_connect` line of

`$link = mysqli_connect('ENDPOINT', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD','innodb',3306);`

it returns the can't connect error.

Can anyone help me out in plain english - how do I do a simple PHP connection to a AWS RDS DB instance?

Comment: Where is the server code running vs where the query browser is running - are they both on the same machine?

Comment: Things like this are almost always an AWS firewall issue (Look under security groups and make sure your webserver is able to access the appropriate port on the database server). Also make sure the DB server itself doesn't have a firewall up (or that the appropriate port is open there too)

Answer (score 2):

Did you configure security group for the RDS instance? And did you remember to open the right port (3306) to your php server ip?

Comment: Did you `x`? Did you `y`? As opposed to Make sure `x` and `y`. It's a small thing and I upvoted as I think you're getting at the right point, but it _is_ two questions... In any case, I'll delete my comments to avoid clutter.